# " during the handling of above exception, another exception occurred " for the first input in the for loop

Tags: python

when I wrote "int" in front of input in for loop the try/except block I wrote for non-integer inputs traceback error " during the handling of the above exception, another exception occurred " is displayed. However, on all of the other inputs in the range, the try/except block is recognized and prints the error message I wrote.

CODE

```
QLEN = 11
MAX_NUM = 12

for i in range(1,QLEN):
  int2 = (random.randint(1,MAX_NUM))
  int1 = (random.randint(1,MAX_NUM))
  print()
  print("Question {}".format(i))
  try:
    ans = int(input("{} + {}: ".format(int1,int2)))
    add(int1,int2,ans)
  except ValueError:
    add(int1,int2,ans)
```

"ADD" FUNCTION

```
def add(a,b,c):
  if a + b != c:
    print("Incorrect")
    print("Correct Answer Was {}".format(a + b))
    return (a + b)
    print()
  else:
    print("Correct")
```

ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 125, in <module>
    ans = int(input("{} + {}: ".format(int1,int2)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 128, in <module>
    add(int1,int2,ans)
NameError: name 'ans' is not defined
```

Comment: That is because in your `except` block you did something to trigger an exception. Also please include the Full Traceback of the exception you are getting

Comment: Thank you, I will include this now. This is my first post.

Answer (score 1):

You tried to execute the same fraudulent code that caused an exception in the try block in the except block. Also the python indentation convention is **4 spaces**, not two. Your original code will produce an error message similar to this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eric/Desktop/ Python_Files/stackoverflow/0008.py", line 21, in <module>
    ans = int(input("{} + {}: ".format(int1,int2)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ans'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eric/Desktop/ Python_Files/stackoverflow/0008.py", line 24, in <module>
    add(int1,int2,ans)
NameError: name 'ans' is not defined
```

Try using the code below (the except block is different)

```py
import random

QLEN = 11
MAX_NUM = 12

def add(a,b,c):
  if a + b != c:
    print("Incorrect")
    print("Correct Answer Was {}".format(a + b))
    return (a + b)
    print()
  else:
    print("Correct")

for i in range(1,QLEN):
  int2 = (random.randint(1,MAX_NUM))
  int1 = (random.randint(1,MAX_NUM))
  print()
  print("Question {}".format(i))
  try:
    ans = int(input("{} + {}: ".format(int1,int2)))
    add(int1,int2,ans)
  except ValueError:
    print("You answered with something that wasn't an integer!")
```

Replacing the except block with anything else, like, in this case a notification that you didn't answer in the correct format, should work.

Here is a sample output:

```
Question 1
9 + 10: 21
Incorrect
Correct Answer Was 19

Question 2
2 + 1: 3
Correct

Question 3
8 + 7: 15
Correct

Question 4
8 + 12: LOL
You answered with something that wasn't an integer!
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` failed with ValueError because it could not parse something which was not an integer. That caused it to trigger the `except` part, which called `add` using `ans`. However, `ans` is an unknown variable because it was never assigned a value (`int` failed), causing another exception *during the handling of the previous one*.

Unlike some languages, in Python if you do not assign a value there will not be any "default" value.

Here is the corrected snippet:

```py
print("Question {}".format(i))
try:
    ans = int(input("{} + {}: ".format(int1,int2)))
except ValueError:
    print("Bad input!")
    continue

add(int1,int2,ans)
```

What you expect to fail is `int`, so you surround it with `try/except`. In case it failed, you `continue` and thus skip the `add` call which is later in the loop. If there were no exceptions, then you have a good `ans` and you can call `add` with all integer arguments.

Also, `print()` after `return (a+b)` can never be executed because `return` will leave the function. Moreover, you do not need outer parenthesis in expressions like `int2 = (random.randint(1,MAX_NUM))` as they only add to the clutter and might be confused for a tuple with one element.

Comment: Thank you, do you recommend that I define ```ans``` as a string within ```except``` so that ```add``` can be called without issue.

Comment: @JackTucker Even though you can send any object type as an argument to functions, I would recommend you do not do that and just stick to one type (in this case all `int`s for `add`). Bad input should not be handled in that function as that is not it's purpose. I edited my answer to give a code snippet.